# Finding subtotal for column in repeater control

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, repeater, databound

I am having trouble finding the subtotal for the "price" column in the repeater control. It does not calculate the subtotal. Thanks in advance!

Here is the markup to the repeater:

```html
<asp:Repeater ID="rptItem" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptItem_ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="rptItem_ItemDataBound">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table id="carttable">
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProductId") %>' /></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImageUrl") %>' CssClass="imagecart" /></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductName") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# String.Concat("ProductDetails.aspx?ProductId=", Eval("ProductId")) %>'></asp:HyperLink></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# String.Format("{0:C}", Eval("Price")) %>'></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtQty" runat="server" Width="50"></asp:TextBox><asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="update" /></td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
            Subtotal:
            <asp:Label ID="lblSubtotal" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Here is the code behind:

```html
protected void rptItem_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "delete")
        {
            List<Item> items = Session["Cart"] as List<Item>;

            var productId = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            var itemToDelete = (from Item i in items
                                where i.ProductId == productId
                                select i).FirstOrDefault();

            items.Remove(itemToDelete);
            Session["Cart"] = items;
        }

        BindData();
    }

    protected void rptItem_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        double subtotal = 0;
        double price = 0;

        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
        {
            price += Convert.ToDouble(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Price"));
            subtotal += price;
        }

        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Footer)
        {
            Label lblSubtotal = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblSubtotal");
            lblSubtotal.Text = subtotal.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception??

Comment: No, I didn't get any exception @KaushikMaheta

Comment: So what's your trouble?

Comment: Price and subtotal are local variable inside rptItem_ItemDataBound, each time you assign it to be equal 0, you may need to move price outside rptItem_ItemDataBound event to be a global variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the variable outside of the `ItemDataBound` event. The problem with your code is that ItemDataBound event is called after every row is bound to the repeater control, so every time your `subtotal` & `price` are getting initialized to `0` thus you are not getting the expected output.

```
double subtotal = 0;
double price = 0;

protected void rptItem_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        price += Convert.ToDouble(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Price"));
        subtotal += price;
    }

    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Footer)
    {
        Label lblSubtotal = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblSubtotal");
        lblSubtotal.Text = subtotal.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this works! Also, do you know why the price gets calculated again if i add another item to cart.  For example, Product A ($1). If I add Product B ($2), it calculates = 1+1+2 @Rahul Singh

Comment: I call DataBind on the page load and delete rptItem_ItemCommand @Rahul Signh

Comment: @RonT - No I mean when you are adding new item to cart? Are you calling `DataBind` method again? Also make sure on Page Load you use `!IsPostBack` and only call DataBind on initial get request.

Comment: No, I am not calling DataBind when I click the add button on a different web form. But when I go to the cart form, DataBind is then called. Yeah I used !IsPostBack on the page load. I'll take a look at the initial get request. @Rahul Singh

Comment: @RonT - Yeah just debug it I mean all the events and check where it is geting incremented cz it's hard to guess without knowing the complete code.

Comment: I figured it out, it was because of the "price += Convert.ToDouble(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Price"));" the += add the price twice. Wow, I never really debugged before but now I understand the importance of debugging @Rahul Singh

Comment: @RonT - Great :) You should debug the code more often and you will learn more :)